# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 endless spinning button and timeout

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have prestashop 1.6.1.4.
Without any change in the files or upgrade suddenly i began to get a timeout error and a forever splinning save buttons:

[image]

I have seen this thread:
[Prestashop Endless Spinning Product Save Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726844/prestashop-endless-spinning-product-save-button)

And i tried this pull https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/5949

The spinning problem stoped but the products were not saved when i clicked on them.

After a few minuted the server (hostgator) blocked the domain becouse of a CPU overquota usage.

I have checked and as soon i try to edit a product the resource usage of the server is fired:

[image]

Like 17 processes are lunched and 3% of the CPU usage just to try to edit the product. And finaly it throws a timeout error.

I will apreciate any help.

Comment: Try to go to /config/defines.inc.php and find `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);` then change it to true, then you can find your problem that takes a lot of time in execution.